# CQL Query on a column with a whitespace

Tags: sql, cql

I wish to do a SELECT query but unfortunately, the database I am working on has a column with whitespace.

Example of query (partial) :

`"WHERE My Column = value"`

CQL says that

> the column name 'My' doesn't exist in the database.

How can I make CQL understand that it has to look for the column "My Column"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what worked for me :

`'WHERE "My Column" = value'`

Answer (score 0):

you can execute query with following change

```
"WHERE [My Column] = value"
```

SQL will take care of blank space between column name. As for blank space column or table name can be assigned to database but you can use it with square bracket ([]).

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am working with CQL queries not SQL. I have attempted to fix it with your solution and it still has a problem with my whitespace.